# Why is assigned variable undefined when running mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have the following piece of codes running in nodejs, mocha, sinon.

```
let urlProp1 = process.env.URL;
...

function sendRequest(uinFin) {
...
let url = "";

    url = urlProp1 + urlProp2
}
```

Test case:

```
...
beforeEach(() => {
        process.env.URL="/url/to/somewhere";

    });
...
```

When running in mocha test case, my urlProp1 becomes undefined when i inspect it. Thus when i inspect my url, it becomes undefined. Can I know why?

Comment: How are you running your mocha test? Are you sure the URL environment variable has the proper value? Try to add `console.log(process.env.URL)` inside the function to find out.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy Yes i am sure. There is value printed out on my console ans as well as during inspection for the env variable.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy is it possible that the variable scope is the issue here?

Comment: it is, if you're redefining urlProp1 anywhere. Also, just saw your test case - that's not how you assign environment variables - those should come from the outside of your process (command line, .env file etc.)

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy I need the env variable to dynamic in my test case as it is part of my test case. But nevertheless, the env variables `process.env.URL` when i inspect shows the values that i injected but `urlProp1` is still undefined

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you require the file with this line
`let urlProp1 = process.env.URL;`
Before you set `process.env.URL` var